# loop curl in cmd

Tags: loops, curl, cmd

Via cmd, I initialize `curl http://path-to-my-domain` to test in something in my site. However , I want to initialize at least 20 times of it. Is there a way to create a .exe file for this so that I can just click on it then it will perform like a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Why an exe? A simple batch file will work. (A text file with a .BAT extension containing commands to be executed)

Not sure what the purpose would be, but to call it 20 times with the same URL you could use:

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 20) do curl http://path-to-my-domain
```

If run from the command line then %%N must change to %N

If you want to call it with multiple URLs, then

```
curl http://path1
curl http://path2
curl http://path3
...
curl http://path20
```